# Identify Firewire device via DirectShow using EUI-64

Tags: video, directshow, uniqueidentifier, firewire

I have 2 Firewire Video Input Devices ([Canopus ADVC-300](http://cdn1.grassvalley.com/unsecure/DL/ADVC300/documentation/ADVC-300_E.pdf)), that I want to connect to a DirectShow filter chain. However before constructing the filter chain, I'd like to know which camera is which (in my case which one is left and which ones is right of the scene to be captured).

Is there a way to read out the [EUI-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EUI-64) (an identifier, unique among all Firewire devices), so that I know which camera I am handling?

EDIT: I may not have been specific enough: I may be able to get the EUI-64 generally, but I think I need to get it via the DirectShow Input Filter, so that I know which camera I am constructing the filter chain with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer myself using GraphStudio. The "DisplayName" property is unique among the Video Input Devices. I found [forum posts explaining how to retrieve it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/9a58868d-d7ea-4982-9ad2-ccc1489c235b/).

Comment: This is how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254440/how-to-find-the-imoniker-used-to-create-a-source-filter, you don't need to read from registry directly.

Comment: Thanks, @Roman. I looked into your answer in the above-mentioned thread and will try later.